# Android-The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type first (Fragment)

Tags: android, xml, random, android-fragments, textview

I'm new to fragments and i'm developing an application using Swipe view with tabs. My aim here is to get a textview display texts stored in the string-array and changes whenever the application is restarted. 
But there seems to be a problem when i'm using findViewById.

Code:

First.java

```
import java.util.Random;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class first extends Fragment{

String[] strArr;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_xml, container, false);
    strArr = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.quote);
             //quote is the name given to the string array

    return rootView;
}




@Override
public void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    refreshTV();
}

void refreshTV(){
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        Random ran = new Random();
        int c = ran.nextInt(strArr.length);
        tv.setText(strArr[c]);


    }

}
```

2.first_xml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#fa6a6a" >

<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@array/quote"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Please Let me know if anything i mentioned is not clear enough.
Thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Fragment` class does not have the `findViewById(...)` method, so you have to get your views from your `rootView` or your `Activity`. I would suggest making your `TextView` a member of your `Fragment`, retrieving it from your `rootView`, and referencing it as needed.

```
public class first extends Fragment {

String[] strArr;
TextView tv;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_xml, container, false);
    tv = rootView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    strArr = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.quote);
             //quote is the name given to the string array

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    refreshTV();
}

void refreshTV(){
        Random ran = new Random();
        int c = ran.nextInt(strArr.length);
        tv.setText(strArr[c]);
    }
}
```

(Edited to remove redundant calls to findViewById.)

Answer (score 4):

Retain the root view returned by inflater.inflate() in onCreateView().

This can later be used to call findViewById() to find any view as per requirements.

```
View mView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xyz, container, false);

    return mView;
}
```

Then anywhere in the class

```
mView.findViewById(R.id.some_view);
```

Alternatively, if you can use

```
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xyz);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to create a `TextView` attribute in your fragment and assigning it in your `onCreateView` method and use this sentence `myTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text1);` and then use it in your `refreshTV` method.

Hope it helps